# Accumulating Arrays in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to create an invoice program in C but it is not doing what I intend on it doing.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
  int choice;
  char item_name[1000][3][20];
  float item_price[1000][3];
  float quantity[1000][3];
  int k;
  int j;


  k=0;
  j=0;
  for (k=0;k<1000;k++)
  {
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Enter the item name: ");
    scanf ("%s", item_name[k][j]); 
    printf ("\n"); 
    printf ("Enter the item price: ");
    scanf ("%f", &item_price[k][j]);
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Enter the item quantity: ");
    scanf ("%f", &quantity[k][j]);
    printf ("\n");

    printf ("|        Quantity         |         Item Name        |        Item Price        |");
    printf ("\n");

    for (j=0;j<1000;j++)
    {
      if (quantity[k][j]==0) break;
      printf ("           %.1f", quantity[k][j]);
      printf ("                          %s", item_name[k][j]);
      printf ("                     %.2f", item_price[k][j]);
      printf ("\n\n");
    }

    printf ("   Would you like to enter another item? Enter '1' for yes and '2' for no: ");
    scanf ("%d", &choice);
    printf ("\n");

    if (choice == 2) break;
    if (k>999) break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output that I want:

```
Enter item name: Chips
Enter item price: 0.70
Enter item quantity: 3

|        Quantity        |          Item Name        |     Item Price    | 
            3                         Chips                    0.70

Would you like to enter another item? Enter '1' for yes and '2' for no: 1
Enter item name: Drinks
Enter item price: 1.00
Enter item quantity: 3

|        Quantity        |          Item Name        |     Item Price    | 
            3                         Chips                    0.70
            3                         Drinks                   1.00

Would you like to enter another item? Enter '1' for yes and '2' for no: 2
```

Comment: What is the error or output you are getting

Comment: The output that i was getting is that after i enter the first values for chips then I go ahead and enter the second set of values for drinks, it overwrites the values for the chips so I always only had one line thus it was not accumulatative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [3] isn't needed.
In the for k loop just referenct [k]
In the for j loop just reference [j]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int choice;
    char item_name[1000][20];
    float item_price[1000];
    float quantity[1000];
    int k;
    int j;


    k=0;
    j=0;
    for (k=0;k<1000;k++)
    {
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Enter the item name: ");
        scanf ("%19s", item_name[k]);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Enter the item price: ");
        scanf ("%f", &item_price[k]);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("Enter the item quantity: ");
        scanf ("%f", &quantity[k]);
        printf ("\n");
        printf ("|        Quantity         |         Item Name        |        Item Price        |");
        printf ("\n");
        for (j=0;j<=k;j++)
        {
            printf ("           %.1f", quantity[j]);
            printf ("                          %s", item_name[j]);
            printf ("                     %.2f", item_price[j]);
            printf ("\n\n");
        }
        printf ("   Would you like to enter another item? Enter '1' for yes and '2' for no: ");
        scanf ("%d", &choice);
        printf ("\n");
        if (choice == 2) break;
        if (k>999) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tnx ALOT, been stuck on this problem for weeks

Answer (score 2):

I think you're better off using a linked list and putting all the item info into a struct, like so

```
typedef struct ItemData
{
  char *name;
  float price;
  float quantity;
} ItemData_t;
```

Note though, that for the name you have to allocate some memory prior to storing the string in there.
Look up how linked lists work, it pretty simple, especially with pointers.